# Linked questions should not appear in the list of related questions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, related-questions, linked-questions

Sometimes (e.g. in [this question of mine](https://serverfault.com/q/432718/113898)) the same question appears twice in the side column - once as a linked question, then again as related. A bug?

> [image]

Comment: My guess is that they're two unrelated algorithms that just do their own thing independent of each other, and the question is both linked *and* related...

Comment: @MarkHenderson: Umm, obviously. The problem is that the 'related' doesn't filter out the linked questions.

Comment: BTW, am I allowed to remove the 'status-bydesign' tag? I contest that...

Comment: No, you may not, as it was put there by a stack exchange employee who is the only person who is entitled to make the decision about by-design or not. Whether or not you agree or disagree, that's the case.

Answer (score 1):

The two categories are independent, linked questions are literally linked on either side and related are what we found to be related.  A question may be both, and that's alright.

Comment: I would say that is not alright, since linked questions have an extreley high chance of being related, and it's not a good idea to waste a spot for related questions - the top spot, even - for a question which is already suggested.

Comment: @einpoklum - On what do you base your assumption?

Comment: I would base it on the reasons for questions being linked: Duplicates, expansions on a certain topic, similar but subtly different questions with very different answers... that covers most links, doesn't it?

Comment: @einpoklum - nope, not even close :)

Comment: Could you elaborate just a bit more than that?